# MySQL get top average entries

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mysql query to return the top 3 courses that have the highest average course rating. I have two tables, Ratings and Courses.

The Ratings table:

```
courseId    rating  
   1           6    
   2           2        
   1           4
   2           5
   3           3
   4           0
   6           0
```

The Courses Table:

```
courseId        cnum        cname
   1            100         name1
   2            112         name2
   3            230         name3
   4            319         name4
   5            122         name5
   6            320         name6
```

I need to return the top 3 courses that have the highest average rating. Any ideas how I could do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Courses.*
FROM   Courses NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   courseId, AVG(rating) avg_rating
  FROM     Ratings
  GROUP BY courseId
  ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
  LIMIT    3
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07768/1/0).